# Выделение запятыми "по большому счету"

Tags: пунктуация

"Победа или же поражение в конкурентной борьбе, по большому счету, зависят от того..." — нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужны, так как *по большому счету* вводное выражение. Вводное выражение легко определить: если его отбросить, предложение продолжает полноценно существовать, потому что вводные (слова, выражения) никогда не выступают членами предложения, только добавляют дополнительную информацию (это может быть субъективное мнение или оценка, ссылка на источник информации...). Автор с помощью вводного выражения (такого как *по большому счету*) выражает свое, субъективное, мнение. Если Вы научитесь отличать вводные слова от членов предложения, а также понимать, какую роль каждый из них выполняет, у вас не будет возникать таких вопросов.

Комментарий к ответу Ларf:

Может, я и ошибаюсь, но никак не укладывается в голове "по большому счету" как наречие в примере про Советы. Это выражение все равно воспринимается как субъективная точка зрения, как оценка через такую-то призму. 
Нашла еще такие значения "по большому счету": не обращая внимания на второстепенные факторы и детали, 
исходя из существа дела, базовых принципов или коренных интересов. 
Также думаю, что "по большому счету" идентично "по сути", которое также может быть и вводным, и невводным.

Вот если подставить значение этого выражения:

Это стало, по большому счету (исходя из существа дела, по сути), крушением Советов как представительной власти. --

Разве здесь не нужны запятые? И интонация или инверсия не должны влиять на расстановку знаков препинания в данном случае. Это то же самое, если бы обращение в начале предложения нужно было бы выделять запятой, а в середине -- не нужно, потому что кто-то может его прочитать без пауз.

А вот в таком контексте "по большому счету" очевидно будет наречием (слова из романа Каверина "Исполнение желаний", из которого и произошло это крылатое выражение):

"Так ведь как жить? Можно жить по маленькому счету, а можно и по большому… По-моему, большой счет — это такое отношение к жизни, которое создано революцией."

Жить - как? - по большому счету (наречие).
Другие примеры:
Спрашивать - как? - по большому счету (по сути).
Отвечать - как? - по большому счету.

Так что мне кажется, что авторы статьи на грамма.ру в данном случае неправы.

Comment: Это достаточно легко решить, если слышишь предложение, или сам его произносишь. А если читаешь без запятых - зачастую это сделать невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение вполне можно прочитать и без паузы, и с логическим ударением на сочетании "по большому счету". Т. е. вовсе не очевидно, что данное сочетание является вводным. "Можно опустить", "можно выбросить" - вообще не считаю за критерий. Многие успешно выбрасывают все, что им непонятно, и разницы не видят. Кроме того, ни в одном справочнике выражение *по большому счету* в качестве вводного не нашла. Справочная служба  "Грамоты" солидарна со справочниками:"Как правило, этот оборот не обособляется".
А вот это мне понравилось.

"По большому счету. В словарях современного русского литературного языка сочетание по большому счету зафиксировано только в наречном значении ‘исходя из самых строгих требований’ (спрашивать по большому счету). Но в примере Это стало по большому счету крушением Советов как представительной власти это выражение можно интерпретировать и как обстоятельство, и как вводное слово. Подчеркнуть употребление конструкции по большому счету в качестве вводной можно изменением порядка слов в предложении: По большому счету, это стало крушением Советов как представительной власти" (gramma.ru).

Т. е. в очередной раз сошлюсь на автора фразы. При таком построении все зависит от смысла, от интонации. А мы еще и окончания фразы не знаем.